# Running a variable script with parameters through a script

Tags: shell

I am sure there is an easier way to do this, but I have yet to figure out what to try next. We are running some jboss applications and I wish to be able to restart these with a input parameter. As I wish to restart more than one application at a time I figured a list would be good. This is comma seperated. This is how far I have gotten thus far.

```
IFS=',';
while read mLine
do
for i in $mLine
do
sh jboss-{$mLine} restart
done;
done < /tmp/apps
```

In general it works if I just write "sh jboss-abcdef restart", but not as long as I write "jboss-${mLine} restart". The latter will return a response from the script ( which is the right script according to the input values ) asking for the parameter which as you can see is in the sh command of this script. The former starts the correct script just like the latter, but unlike the latter, the first one actually restarts the server in question.

One could argue that I put one like for each applcation as well, but since not all applications needs to be restarted every time that would make me alot of if's this and if's that to find out which lines would have to be run, and thus defeating the purpose of neat and simple ...

Any ideas would be appreciated as I'm willing to try most to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for app in "$@"; do
    sh "jboss-$app" restart
done
```

Then you can pass a space-separated list of app names to the script

```
./restart-apps app1 app2 app3 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great :) Got some new problems but atleast it's one step closer.